# Selecting partially bolded DrawingText in Catia Drawing workbench

Tags: vba, catia

I'm currently developing a Catia vba script to look for specific texts in a plan, within the Drawing workbench.

For this particular macro, I need to search **bold** text. But the thing is I know that the DrawingText object has an attributed called *bold* that evaluates to True if ALL the text is bolded, but not if just a word is bolded.

Example:

- **This is my text** -> True
- **This** is my text -> False

What would be a good way to indentify this partially bolded DrawingText objects?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

aText.GetParameterOnSubString(catBold,startPos,numChars)

will return 1 if all the characters in the specifed substring are **Bold**, 0 otherwise.

So first check if your sub-string is in the text by using InStr(aText.Text,subString). and if it is, use this test to see if is in Bold.

Comment: Thanks! I don't know how I didn't find that function before!